# Where to find older source&binary package versions?

Tags: package-management

I know that when a package update appears in the repository, its older version disappears from there. But what if new version has a regression? Where can I find previous ones?

Note: I don't mean package from older distro release or anything like that. I mean the version directly preceding current, e.g. if wine-1.5.29 is current, I need wine-1.5.28 and maybe earlier ones. Of course, wine is a bad example since I can find any version on their website, but this isn't the case for all packages.

Searching in `/var/cache/apt/archives` is not an option because it may be occasionally cleaned by `apt-get clean`.

Comment: take a look at this site... [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) And this... [PackageArchive](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/PackageArchive)

Comment: @MrSeed suppose I search for previous version of acpid, 2.0.17. I get to that site and all I found is 2.0.18 for Raring and 2.0.16 for Quantal. What I need instead is version 2.0.17 for e.g. Raring (if it has been packaged of course). I.e. I need the previous version which would have been installed on my current distro if I upgraded a bit earlier.

Comment: Launchpad is where Ubuntu host packages.  2.0.17 does not appear to exist any more as a built package but you can find the source code here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpid/1:2.0.17-1ubuntu2

Comment: @WarrenHill oh, that's great. It seems I can view publishing history for any package and find the source and ubuntu patches for it, right? If this is so, I'd accept your answer if you format it as an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ubuntu uses Launchpad to host all its packages specifically here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu

From here you can find the source code to any package simply by searching

For example by searching for for acpid you are taken here

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpid

from here you can **View the full publishing history**,  or **View full change log** to find all releases and select the one you want.

In many cases you will also be able to find binaries.  However I have seen examples where the binaries are missing.  I'm not sure why but I presume this is when the main truck has changed more than once between Ubuntu releases.

The developer may have updated the source from upstream project for the first upstream change, tested it and published the source then immediately updated the with the second update and published again with the current upstream release.