# Ubuntu 18.04 boots into blackscreen

Tags: boot

I try to install Ubuntu 18.04 as my second os on my laptop (Asus UX433) but when i boot from an usb stick and choose any of the boot options my screen blacks out. Sometimes even before i selected something. Also replacing quiet splash by nomodeset hasnt helped me. What can I try next to get it running?

Comment: May I suggest you look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155634/intel-microcode-package-upgrade-in-ubuntu-18-04-leads-to-unbootable-system ?

Comment: The problem is that neither nouveau.modeset=0 nor nomodeset have worked and that i cant work with the terminal because i haven't installed ubuntu yet and i cant run it without installation because i also get a black screen